# Finding the radius of incircle of a triangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

The question is -

> [image: In the figure]
>
> **AB** and **AC** are the circular arcs of center **O'** and **O** of radius **5** units respectively. **OO' = 6** unit. In **$\Delta$ABC**, **AB = AC** and a circle is inscribed in the triangle. The radius of the circle can be written as **$\frac{a}{\sqrt b +1}$** where **a, b** are integers, **a+b=?**

My try:
At first,

- AO = 5
- AO' = 5
- OC = 5
- O'B = 5
- OO' = 6
- OB = OO' - O'B = 6-5 = 1
- O'C = 1
- BC = OO' - (OB+O'C) = 6-2 = 4

So,**BC** = 4,

- In **$\Delta$AOO'** ,(using Law of cosines) AO$^2$ = AO'$^2$ + OO'$^2$ - 2AO'$*$OO'$*$$\cos$$\angle$AO'O

  So **$\angle$AO'O** = 53.13°
- **$\Delta$AO'B** is Isosceles , i know AO' = 5, BO' = 5 and $\angle$AO'B = 53.13°

  So base AB = 2×AO'×$\sin$(0.5×$\angle$AO'B) = 4.4721.

So AC = 4.4721

Now i know the length of AB, AC and BC, and i can find the radius of incircle of **$\Delta$ABC**
so the radius= **$\frac{\sqrt{s(s-AB)(s-AC)(s-BC)}}{s}$**

$s = (AB+AC+BC)/2 = (4.4721+4.4721+4)/2 = 6.4721.$

Also

**${\sqrt{s(s-AB)(s-AC)(s-BC)}} = 8$** but the value of **s** is 6.4721, how can I express **$\frac{8}{6.4721} $** as **$\frac{a}{\sqrt b +1}$** ??

Comment: You should do all your intermediate steps in exact form to get the value of $s$ in the form $\frac{a}{\sqrt b+1}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$AO = AO' = 5$ so perp from $A$ to $OO'$ will meet at the midpoint of $OO'$, say $H$. Then, $OH = O'H = 3$

So, $AH = \sqrt{AO^2 - OH^2} = \sqrt{5^2 - 3^2} = 4$

Now, $BH = BC/2 = 2$ and $AB = AC = \sqrt{AH^2 + BH^2} = \sqrt{4^2 + 2^2} = 2 \sqrt5$

Sub-perimeter of $\triangle ABC$,
$s = \frac 12 (4 + 2 \cdot 2 \sqrt5) = 2 (1 + \sqrt5)$

Area of $~\triangle ABC, [ABC] = \frac 12 \cdot BC \cdot AH = 8$

If $r$ is the inradius of $\triangle ABC$, we know $[ABC] = r\cdot s$ $$\implies r = \dfrac{4}{1 + \sqrt5}$$

$ \therefore ~a + b = 9$